# Convert Photoshop values to ColorMatrix?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, photoshop, colormatrix

Ive edited the following properties of an image in Photoshop, and am looking for the corrosponding Color-Matrices for them. Hue/Saturation/Contrast/Color-Overlay/RGB-Channel Mixer/Levels.

Ive so far solved Hue/Saturation/Contrast. The remaining 3 im not clear about how to start.

```
 _filter.hue = function( rotation ) {
    rotation = (rotation || 0)/180 * Math.PI;
    var cos = Math.cos(rotation),
        sin = Math.sin(rotation),
        lumR = 0.213,
        lumG = 0.715,
        lumB = 0.072;

    _filter.colorMatrix([
            lumR+cos*(1-lumR)+sin*(-lumR),lumG+cos*(-lumG)+sin*(-lumG),lumB+cos*(-lumB)+sin*(1-lumB),0,0,
            lumR+cos*(-lumR)+sin*(0.143),lumG+cos*(1-lumG)+sin*(0.140),lumB+cos*(-lumB)+sin*(-0.283),0,0,
            lumR+cos*(-lumR)+sin*(-(1-lumR)),lumG+cos*(-lumG)+sin*(lumG),lumB+cos*(1-lumB)+sin*(lumB),0,0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ]);
};


 _filter.saturation = function( amount ) {
    var x = (amount || 0) * 2/3 + 1;
    var y = ((x-1) *-0.5);
    _filter.colorMatrix([
        x, y, y, 0, 0,
        y, x, y, 0, 0,
        y, y, x, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ]);
};


 _filter.contrast = function( amount ) {
    var v = (amount || 0) + 1;
    var o = -128 * (v-1);

    _filter.colorMatrix([
        v, 0, 0, 0, o,
        0, v, 0, 0, o,
        0, 0, v, 0, o,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ]);
};
```

Here are the filters and input-properties required-

- Color-Overlay : HEX-Color, Opacity & BlendMode
- RGB-Channel   : RGB values for each channel, Constant & BlendMode
- Levels        : High , Mid & Low values

[image: Screenshot of 3-Properties]

Comment: what do the values range from in your contrast and saturation?

Comment: have you got any solution? I also want to set values from photoshop which is given to create a unique image in ColorMatrix.